# Angular2 FormBuilder: adding group validation for 2 input fields

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

The form object getting created in parent component using 'FormBuilder' like below

```
constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.testForm = this._fb.group({});
}
```

The instance of the form object will passed to child component, so that input fields in child component can be bind to parent component form. 
 (Have created child component for different types of input fields, so that they can be re-used)

```
<shared-ux-input-password
    [parentForm]="testForm"
    [isParentFormSubmitted]="false"
    [inputFieldControlName]="'password'"
    [confirmPasswordRequired]="true">
 </shared-ux-input-password>
```

In child component, input fields are created using below code

```
let passwordFieldControl: FormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.customValidatorFunction));
 this.parentForm.addControl(this.inputFieldControlName, passwordFieldControl);
```

Since this child component deals with passwords and confirm password, same custom validator function needs to be fired to check if both password and confirm password matched or not.

Now how to fire same custom validator function which can grab the values from both fields and give error if password and confirm password are not matched ?

Thanks for the help.